# Apache Druid: My VM hangs when I try to load quickstart data

Tags: druid

I'm new to Apache Druid. I used Azure VM (Standard B2s (2 vcpus, 4 GiB memory)) to install apache druid and then tried to load the quick-start tutorial json data (wikiticker-2015-09-12-sampled.json.gz) using console.
I followed all the instructions as mentioned in the DRUID tutorial on their official site. I tried multiple times but each time the VM hangs and make it unresponsive. Am I missing anything/need to do any configuration changes for task to execute before loading the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Druid comes with several startup configuration profiles for a range of machine sizes.

***Single server reference configurations**

Nano-Quickstart: 1 CPU, 4GB RAM

Micro-Quickstart: 4 CPU, 16GB RAM

Small: 8 CPU, 64GB RAM (~i3.2xlarge)

Medium: 16 CPU, 128GB RAM (~i3.4xlarge)

Large: 32 CPU, 256GB RAM (~i3.8xlarge)

X-Large: 64 CPU, 512GB RAM (~i3.16xlarge)
*

To start the Druid services I was using the micro configuration profile:
./bin/start-micro-quickstart

However, my machines as mentioned above is more of a Nano configuration and hence should be using below command to start the Druid services:

./bin/start-nano-quickstart

I was now able to successfully load and query the data file.

Please check your machine configuration before running the service start command.

Regards,

Udayan